# Run Function after element appear in DOM

Tags: jquery

How can I remove a class from a element after it is loaded in the DOM ?

**Following situation:**

If a element with the classname `selected` appear in DOM I like to remove the class `highlight` from it.

**Example:**

```
<div class="selected highlight">
<div class="group">Material</div>
<div class="option">350g Chromo-Sulfatkarton matt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(function(){ $("div.selected").removeClass("highlight") });` ?

Comment: How are you adding the element?

Comment: You want it to be highlighted for a short period of time right? Just to indicate it is a new element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every answer uses jQuery. In my opinion CSS is more relevant here.

I made this snippet using CSS `keyframes` and `animation`.

```js
function create() {
  var element = $("<p class='selected highlight'>" + Math.random() + "</p>");
  $("#container").prepend(element);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  -webkit-animation: highlight 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: highlight 1s;
  -o-animation: highlight 1s;
  animation: highlight 1s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: none;
  }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='create()'>Create an element</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you load the element with the page, in which case you would listen for the `DOM ready event`, or some other event, the following code should be fired when the appropriate event happens:

```
$('.selected.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
```

If listening for **DOM ready event** the code would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('.selected.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.selected").ready(function() {
 $("div.selected").removeClass("highlight") 
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the DOMNodeInserted insert event of jquery as below

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(e.target).removeClass('highlight')
  }
});
```